# Error when using Entity Framework Core tools in GitHub workflow

Tags: .net-core, entity-framework-core, github-actions

I am trying to create a GitHub workflow that will run an Entity Framework Core migration on my database.

The C# project containing my data model is targeting `netcoreapp3.1`.

Here is the bulk of the workflow: (trigger conditions omitted)

```
jobs:
  migrate:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2

    - name: Setup .NET Core
      uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v1
      with:
        dotnet-version: 3.1.301

    - name: Install dependencies
      run: dotnet restore

    - name: Build
      run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore

    - name: Install EF Core tools
      run: |
        dotnet tool install --global dotnet-ef
        dotnet tool restore

    - name: Migrate
      run: dotnet ef database update
```

When the workflow runs, I get this error:

```
Run dotnet ef database update
It was not possible to find any compatible framework version
The framework 'Microsoft.NETCore.App', version '1.0.0' was not found.
  - The following frameworks were found:
      3.1.5 at [/opt/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/shared/Microsoft.NETCore.App]

You can resolve the problem by installing the specified framework and/or SDK.

The specified framework can be found at:
  - https://aka.ms/dotnet-core-applaunch?framework=Microsoft.NETCore.App&framework_version=1.0.0&arch=x64&rid=ubuntu.18.04-x64
##[error]Process completed with exit code 150.
```

I have also tried specifying the version when installing the EF Core tools (`--version 3.1.0`) but this doesn't change anything.

Why I am getting this error? How can I fix it?

---

**Update:**

I added a task to the workflow with these commands, right before the failing migration task:

```
dotnet --list-sdks
dotnet tool list --global
```

Output of `dotnet --list-sdks`:

```
3.1.301 [/opt/hostedtoolcache/dncs/3.1.301/x64/sdk]
```

Output of `dotnet tool list --global`:

```
Package Id      Version      Commands 
--------------------------------------
dotnet-ef       3.1.6        dotnet-ef
```

What is looking for .NET Core 1.0.0?

Comment: Maybe print out the PATH environment variable?

Answer (score 0):

I got this to work by replacing `dotnet ef` with `dotnet-ef` on the last line of the example. I also noticed that the `dotnet-ef` will restore and build, so some steps in the workflow are redundant.